# What is the GitHub API resource type of non-classic Projects?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-projects

How can we access data about non-classic GitHub Projects?

The official [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/projects/projects?apiVersion=2022-11-28) defines API resource type `Project` for this purpose but with this only classic Project board data can be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new projects v2 is not in the REST api, only in GraphQL.

Check the calls in the GitHub docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/automating-your-project/using-the-api-to-manage-projects